# How can I disable memory leak logging in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, memory-leaks

I would like to know if there is a way to disable the built-in memory leak logging that Visual Studio (2005, if it matters) does when ending a process.

When I'm debugging a big piece of code, I might want to only test a specific feature before investigating leaks. My problem is that when I kill the process, leak logging takes a lot of time. Sometimes I can wait more than a minute for all the dumping to take place.

Thank you very much

Comment: maybe your program contains a call to `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`, if so, comment it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is called when your program is compiled in debug mode. You can turn it off this behaviour with a call to the function

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(0);
```

Its usage is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But fixing those memory leaks would still be wise. Normally it some big static objects hold all the memory. You can refactor them from static objects declared in a cpp file by using enclosing them inside a class which creates the object at first access in the getter function. Now you can safely delete your statics at program exit as last call in your main method. That does fix the memory leak and your report will be much shorter.

Yours,
  Alois Kraus

Comment: Indeed, I always fix my memory leaks, it's just that I like to choose when I do so. Sadly, in my work environment, things are rarely as simple as to delete statics at the end of the main method. We have more than 500 modules which interact together, and most of the time, a specific module (DLL) is causing all the trouble. I usually use third party software to debug leaks, as their output is generally much more useful (to me at least) than that of Visual Studio. Thanks a lot for your answer.